# Delay 1.0 opacity on span, even though parent div has already 1.0 opacity?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I realize this may not have a solution outside of javascript, but perhaps someone out there can figure out a way to do this with pure css.

I have a parent div and child:

```
<div class="parent">
    Text Text Text Text <span class = "delay">TEXT</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
    opacity: 0.0;
    -webkit-transition:all;
    -moz-transition:all;
    -o-transition: all;
    transition: all;
    transition-duration: .5s;
}
.delay{
    -webkit-transition:all;
    -moz-transition:all;
    -o-transition: all;
    transition: all;
    transition-duration: 1s; //make this one take .5 seconds longer to show!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay):

```
transition-delay: 0.5s
```

Example:

```css
.parent,
.parent .child {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s opacity linear;
}
.parent .child {
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
body:hover .parent,
body:hover .parent .child {
    opacity: 1;
}
/* Extra to show you where to hover over */
body {
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
body:before {
    content: 'Hover here';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    Text Text Text Text <span class="child">TEXT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it has the same effect as transition-duration. Because no matter what, it seems that since the whole div shows i half a second, the opacity for the span kicks in a half second too late.

Comment: It works, what was I missing, was it that I didn't specify the type of transition to both the parent and child or was it the hover on the parent of the parent (aka the body in this case since I didn't specify)? I'm a bit confused, do you mind explaining in a bit more detail.